# react native implements directory structure tree effect

Tags: react-native

I'm newbie that learning react native and I want to implements directory structure tree effect like below.

Is there any 3rd part libs which could help me?

thanks..

[image]

Comment: For the next time, you might want to use https://react.parts/native to search for libs, most useful ones are listed there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [collapsible](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-collapsible) for the collapse behaviour and a normal list for the rest of the behaviour.